# Pass data to gitolite-VREF via push

Tags: git, gitolite

For my existing gitolite3-installation I want to add anonymous access, restricted to a certain number of repositories. Reading should be allowed for all these repositories, while write-operations should be protected.

For that I thought of passing a token with the push to the gitolite-repositories. A VREF recieves the token and checks if it's valid. If it is, the write-operation on the repository is allowed. The gitolite-conf should look like this:

```
repo @anonrepos
    RW = @all

    option deny-rules = 1
    - VREF/MYTOKENREF = @all
```

(If the config contains errors, then I copied them wrong from the pc where they reside)
And for the vref I thought of:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

token = input()
if is_valid(token): # TODO: define is_valid
    exit(0) # Allow the push
else:
    exit(1) # Deny it
```

So much for theory. When I try to push, I get an error because pythons `input()` raises an EOFError. So I can't pass information to the vref via stdin and not via `sys.argv` either.

Or am I wrong? Is there some way to pass an token to my vref, maybe via some git-command-line-trickery? Or is there some other way I can allow an anonymous push (literally everyone could push, so i need to protect these repositories) if I am sure the person behind it is legitimate? I was thinking about whitelisting the commit-id of the commit that is about to be pushed, but that isn't a flexible way to do it.

**Note:** The procedure for someone to push should be like his: That someone messages me that he wants to push to a repository, I create a token and send it to him and at last he pushes to the repository successfully using the supplied token.

Comment: The general rule for this stuff is "pass by environment variable". I am not sure how to set that up with gitolite specifically though.

Comment: @torek that's a good idea, though I'd like to make pushing as easy as possible and passing environmental variables is not easy to set up on windows systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to define a group of user that you don't populate.

```
repo test-ldap-devel
    RW+    =    @devel
```

To determine if a user is in that devel group (and authorize to push), you write a program which, given a username, queries a user referential and returns a space-separated list of groups that the user is a member of.
Then put the full path to this program in an [`rc`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc/) variable called `GROUPLIST_PGM`, like so:

```
GROUPLIST_PGM           =>  '/home/git/bin/ldap-query-groups',
```

This is usually done with an LDAP referential in mind (as [in this example](https://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/gitolite-openldap/)), but you could use any other referential.

That could replace the notion of token which seems problematic to pass along.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it and try to get it working

Comment: I still haven't tried it, I had other things to do. But I agree that using LDAP is the way to go. I'll do something else than what you suggested, but I'll mark you as answer until I create an answer describing what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You should Read The Fine Manual. Gitolite VREFs are an extension of `update` hooks, and thus take their input on the command line, not via stdin.

http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref/#what-arguments-are-passed-to-the-vref-maker

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks